# Cannot use OAuth 2.0 ROPC (Resource Owner Password Credentials flow) even using @tenant.onmicrosoft.com account

Tags: powershell

I thought I followed the doc below carefully but I still cannot use ROPC even with @tenant.onmicrosoft.com account.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Can someone please enlighten me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to URL encode the parameters of your request body.

Try the below script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$client_id = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("<client_id>")
$client_secret = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("<client_secret>")
$tenant = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("<tenant_id>")
$user = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("<user>")
$password = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("<user_password>")
$scopes = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("<scopes>")

$AuthUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$AuthBody = "grant_type=password&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&username=$user&scope=$scopes&password=$password"

$Authentication = 
    Invoke-RestMethod   -Method Post `
                        -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded `
                        -Uri $AuthUri `
                        -Body $AuthBody

$Authentication
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio.  I just tried it out but same AADSTS50126 error.  I have checked to make sure I could log on using the username and password.